# Openstreetmap Div is Not Centered in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am using OSM in my html page, and I have a map div where I load the map.

For some reason, whatever I do, after it loads - the map div doesn't seem to respond to text-align:center and margin:auto and get centred (as every other div does).

Anyone knows what to do?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of map framework/library are you using? Perhaps leaflet, or openlayers?

Comment: I am using OpenLayers.js

Comment: Please try recreating the problem in a jsfiddle so we can see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I looked further into it (trying to make a jsfiddle), and I thought that maybe some css or style which contains my div made it that way.

I used `!important` on both `text-align:centre` and `margin:auto` and it worked.

Thanks for the comments! (less thanks to the guys who marked me down a bit for the question :) ).